# The meaning of もそもそ/ mosomoso when describes someone getting up in the morning

Tags: meaning, words, manga

When reading, I met this word and don't understand much (my guess is that it means "tired and slowly getting up"). The sentence describes a character who's waking up in the morning.

> もそもそと起き上がり、布団を片付ける。

Answer (score 4):

According to [日本国語大辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%82%E3%81%9D%E3%82%82%E3%81%9D/) the word means:

> ［副］(スル)「もぞもぞ2」に同じ。「―と起き上がる」

Aka it has the same meaning as definition 2 of もぞもぞ.
Looking at the [same dictionary's definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%82%E3%81%9E%E3%82%82%E3%81%9E/#jn-219200) for もぞもぞ:

> ２ 動作や態度がはっきりしないさま。また、落ち着かないようすで、からだの一部分を動かすさま。もそもそ。「ばつが悪そうに―している」

My translation:

> Movements or attitude are not distinct. Or, an appearance of not being calm and having one part of the body moving. Also もそもそ.

I'm guessing it's the former meaning as the latter seems not as related. I think in this case, the movements of the person getting up are not distinct, likely because of being under the covers.